# Celery perform only synchronous tasks

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, git-submodules, schedule

I have to work on submodule repository, so I would prefer to run only synchronous tasks. I'm using celery pending tasks to update my repo periodically and also I have to perform the same task after user request.

Here is Celery schedule config:

```
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
     'sync': {
         'task': 'app.task_to_sync',
         'schedule': 0.2
     }
}
```

(schedule is set to 0.2 s. for tests).

And here is user request call:

```
task_to_sync.apply().get()
```

I set those settings to prevent async call's:

```
settings.task_always_eager = True
settings.task_eager_propagates = True
```

but tasks called by users are collide with scheduled. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Using Celery beat, "eager" tasks and also scheduling arbitrary tasks makes no sense. The "eager" settings are, in my humble opinion, good only for testing purposes. You will probably be more happy with the `solo` worker or the default `prefork` with a single worker process (`--concurrency=1`).